# Importing Div() from module to main.py doesn't work in bokeh

Tags: html, bokeh

I'm creating dashboard app using bokeh. The hierarchy of the package is below:

bokeh_app 
├── config.py 
├── main.py 
└── templates 
    
└── index.html

When I define Div() inside main.py, the dashboard works fine. But if I define Div() inside config.py and use in main.py by importing config.py, after I'm reloading the page in server it starts to fail and doesn't work. 
 How can I define Div() in another modules and use it in main.py?

I tried it in main.py and it works. But when I tried it in another module and start to use it in main.py by importing it starts to fail.